# php error compression mod_deflate gzip compression

Tags: php, apache, gzip, mod-deflate

I follow this way [compression 1](http://rakaz.nl/2006/12/make-your-pages-load-faster-by-combining-and-compressing-javascript-and-css-files.html)
and
[compression 2](http://robotslacker.com/2010/11/dynamically-combine-and-minify-your-javascript-and-css-files-with-codeigniter/#comment-344)

how to compression with mod_deflate? I've followed the above link and success to compress but browser can not read compression? 
I get an error when I open the css and js files in a browser!

**SyntaxError: illegal character**

��{{�F�7���"ƫ

and

KÊO©¬NJLÎN/Ê/ÍKÑMÎÏÉ/²RN2H6II­�ó>å¿rŸ—Ï9?ýSúg½/úž;RSŸ‘‡™§çZV†¤ü”Êê¤Ääìô¢üÒ¼Ýäüœü"+å$ƒd“”ÔZ�

```
Response Headers

Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  127
Content-Type    text/css
Date    Wed, 18 Dec 2013 07:15:22 GMT
Expires Fri, 17 Jan 2014 14:15:22 +0700
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified   Wed, 18 Dec 2013 13:17:18 +0700
Server  Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.26
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.26
```

anybody please...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are compressing the code twice, once with PHP and once with mod_deflate.

Could this be the case?

Comment: I did not add mod_deflate in htaccess but I turn the module on apache

Comment: I am not so sure if you also output gzipped content.. Your content-type = gzip and this should be deflate. So now your content is deflated but is being parsed gzipped, that will not work and you will get jibberish. What are the headers when you disable mod_deflate?

Comment: I've been an inactive mod_deflate and still get response headers Connection 
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Type text/javascript

Comment: so that means your code is already being compressed, and compressing it with gzip and afterwards with deflate will get bad results.. you need to find where your content is being gzipped, inside your PHP, .htaccess, etc. For PHP see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Comment: thanks flashin has helped...This has been successfully ..I disable zlib.output_compression = On to Off..thanks broo